# How to put mutual followers/followings at top of the array when calling get followers/following api?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm calling a get API for a list of followers of another user, I want to put the users who I already follow on top of the list. How can I do that efficiently in laravel

this is how I have done it,

```
$user_details = User::with('followings:name,username,about_me,photo_url,leader_id as id')->where('id', $userId)->select('id')->first();
    
$my_details = User::with('followings:leader_id as id')->where('id', $request->logged_in_user->id)->select('id')->first()->toArray();
            $ids = array_column($my_details['followings'], 'id');

            $sortedfollowings = [];
            foreach ($followings as $key => $value) {
                if(in_array($value->id, $ids)){
                    array_unshift($sortedfollowings, $value);
                } else {
                    array_push($sortedfollowings, $value);
                }
            }
```

I'm sorting list using foreach and if else, but it's not efficient when the list is like million followers.

Comment: Please can you show the code you have that gets the followers.

Answer (score 1):

This is more of an algorithm type of issue. This also depends on if you're using a package or not. Being this said, and not that much information provided and/or examples of what you've tried, I'll proceed explaining the process:

1.- A `foreach` loop that checks through your followings.

2.- Inside that loop, you add a conditional (`if`) that checks if any of your followings follow the `id` of the user profile you're visiting.

3.- Add into an array the users that follow that account.

4.- Send that array separately to your front-end.

5.- Merge that array in the beginning of the whole fetch.

6.- Exclude duplicates.

Again, I don't know which front-end you're using. I don't have any sample code, so I just proceeded with an explanation of how it can work.

This is a matter of loops and array manipulation.